# "color to Alpha" not active in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I have an image and I want the background to be converted to transparent pixels.

In `Colors` the option `Color to Alpha` is not activated. The option "Add Alpha channel" is as well gray (not active).

Comment: What color mode does the image use?

Comment: @gronostaj As far as I can tell you can use C2A on indexed images.

Answer (score 0):

If you are positive there is an alpha channel, the other possibility is that the active "drawable" is not the layer itself. It can be the layer mask, or a channel (typically after *Select>Save to channel*).

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this: In "Image" select "Mode" then select "RGB". At this point the option "Color to Alpha" gets activated.